# Has anyone managed to successfully host a WebView2 control in a ToolWindow in a C# "Visual Studio" VSIX extension project?

Tags: wpf-controls, visual-studio-2022, vsix, webview2

I have a Visual Studio VSIX project that currently uses the hideously outdated IE-based `WebBrowser` control. It seems like Microsoft don't want us to use that control anymore as they've deprecated it, and they've even made some changes to it that make it not display the way it used to. Modern websites like GitHub etc don't display correctly in it either. But AFAIK they haven't provided a **working** `WebView2` that doesn't require a whole bunch of workarounds to be hosted in a `ToolWindow` control like the `WebBrowser` control can be.

In Task Manager I see that Visual Studio 2022 now using a number of WebView2 controls internally, possibly even in VSIX packages. But there's no guidance for how WE can do that.

[image: Visual Studio Using Several WebView Controls]

I just want to replace my outdated `WebBrowser` control with a new `WebView2` control, but all of the documentation that I've been able to find seems to either be out of date, extremely complex, or only mentions WPF applications, not being hosted in a WPF `ToolWindow` `UserControl` in a VSIX package.

I'm not wanting to do anything more fancy than displaying fairly simple html, or XML data. The team who created the WebView2 control have made it ridiculously complicated to install, and to consume, with nothing specific to making a Visual Studio extension containing one.

So, has anyone managed to successfully do what I've described?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since when, but this is definitely possible. Here is an minimal example:

XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserControl x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyToolWindowControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:Wpf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
             >
    <Grid>
        <Wpf:WebView2 Name="webView"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CS:

```cs
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
namespace MyNameSpace;

[Guid(PackageGuids.MyToolWindow)]
public class MyToolWindow : ToolWindowPane
{
    public MyToolWindow()
        : base(null)
    {
        Content = new MyToolWindowControl();
    }
}

public partial class MyToolWindowControl : UserControl, IComponentConnector
{
    public MyToolWindowControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.Run(async delegate{
            InitializeWebViewAsync();
        }); 
    }

    private async Task InitializeWebViewAsync()
    {
        // create webview2 environment and load the webview
        string webviewDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        webviewDirectory = Path.Combine(webviewDirectory, "MyWebView2Directory");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(webviewDirectory);

        CoreWebView2Environment env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, webviewDirectory);
        
        // load the webview2
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);

        webView.Source = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    }
}
```